# In the solution to this problem, why is the electron charge omitted?

Tags: pn-junction

The problem reads as follows:

> A silicon pn junction with a cross-sectional area of 10<sup>-4</sup>
> cm<sup>2</sup> has the following properties at T = 300K:
>
> **n region:**
>
> \$N_d = 10^{-17} cm^3\$
> \$\tau_{p0} = 10^{-7} s\$
> \$\mu_n = 850cm^2/V \cdot s\$
> \$\mu_p = 320cm^2/V \cdot s\$
>
> **p region:**
>
> \$N_a = 5×10^{15} cm^3\$
> \$\tau_{n0} = 10^{-6} s\$
> \$\mu_n = 1250 cm^2/V \cdot s\$
> \$\mu_p = 420 cm^2/V \cdot s\$
>
> (a) Sketch the thermal equilibrium energy-band diagram of the pn
> junction, including the values of the Fermi level with respect to the
> intrinsic level on each side of the junction. (b) Calculate the
> reverse-saturation current I at a forward-bias voltage of 0.5 V. (c)
> Determine the ratio of the hole current to total current at the space
> charge edge \$x_n\$.

The saturation current (asked for in part (b)) is correctly calculated as 4.48 × 10<sup>-15</sup> A. The reverse saturation current due to the bias is however calculated this way:

$$I = I_s \cdot \exp\left(\frac{V_bias}{kT}\right)$$
$$I = 4.48 × 10^{-15} × \exp\left(\frac{0.5}{0.0259}\right)$$
$$I = 1.08 \mu A$$

...which is wrong AFAIK. Shouldn't it be done this way:

$$I = I_s \cdot \exp\left(\frac{qV_{bias}}{kT} - 1\right)$$
$$I = 4.48 × 10^{-15} × \exp\left(\frac{1.6 × 10^{-19} × 0.5}{0.0259} - 1\right)$$
$$I = 1.65 × 10^{-9} \mu A$$

Comment: Link to the internet page of the original problem is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they should include the basic charge *e*. But they have gotten the correct numerical answer, because when they substituted for \$kT\$ they used the value for \$\frac{kT}{q}\$.

That is,

$$\frac{kT}{q}\approx 0.026\ {\rm V}$$

For solving problems of this type, it's easier to just remember this value as the "thermal voltage", often designated \$V_T\$. Then the Shockley diode equation becomes

$$I = I_s \left[\exp\left( \frac{V}{V_T}\right)  - 1\right].$$

(Also notice, in your solution, you moved the -1 term inside the exponential function, which is incorrect)

So, while they dropped the \$q\$ from their expression, they actually used it when they calculated the numerical value.

In your solution, you just accepted their value for \$kT\$ and thus got an incorrect final result. If you want to account for \$q\$ separately, you should use

$$kT=(1.38\times10^{-23}\ {\rm J\cdot K^{-1}})(300\ {\rm K})=4.14\times 10^{-21}\ {\rm J}.$$

Comment: Thank you. What about the minus 1? Shouldn't it be there?

Comment: @WaisKamal, try calculating with and without it and see if it changes the answer. Watch out, in your equation you put the -1 inside the exp function, but it should be outside.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. So the -1 is actually there but was omitted due to its insignificance. Do I get you correctly?

Comment: @WaisKamal, yes, that's correct.

Comment: Ok, that's kind of you. Thanks a lot!